# Импорт пакета находящегося на уровень выше в GO

Tags: golang, импорт

Имеется пакет Config и Services. Сервисам нужен доступ к конфигу. 
пока делаю так

```
import "../Config"
```

А какие еще есть варианты?

Такой же вопрос с дочерним пакетом.
Наприме есть пакет Services и Services/ServiceName
и например что бы использовать методы из ServiceName в пакете Services приходится:

```
import "../Services/ServiceName"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант с относительными путями может использоваться, НО работает он только если компилировать файл напрямую, например
go build asd.go

Если же компилировать пакет целиком, то относительные пути не работают и нужно прописывать полный путь от $GOPATH/src

например если есть пакеты

```
github.com/rekby/tmp
github.com/rekby/tmp/asd.go, export Func1

github.com/rekby/tmp/sub1
github.com/rekby/tmp/sub1/sub2
github.com/rekby/tmp/sub1/sub2/asd.go, export Func2
```

То (чтобы код всегда компилировался независимо от формы вызова) в sub1/main.go нужно писать так

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/rekby/tmp"
    "github.com/rekby/tmp/sub1/sub2"
)

func main(){
   fmt.Println(tmp.Func1(), sub2.Func2())
}
```

Если написать

```
import (
    "fmt"
    tmp ".."
    "../sub1/sub2"
)

func main(){
   fmt.Println(tmp.Func1(), sub2.Func2())
}
```

то код скомпилируется только при вызове "go build main.go", но НЕ "go build" из папки проекта или "go build github.com/rekby/tmp/sub1" или "go get github.com/rekby/tmp/sub1"