# Пакеты в golang, находящиеся в других пакетах. Как организовать структуру?

Tags: golang, package

Решил структурировать код и разделить его по пакетам.
Получилось, что Главный пакет разбит на несколько файлов в директории и содержит `Пакет1.1` а этот пакет содержит ещё `Пакет 2.1` . В итоге сыпятся ошибки из за того, что неверно что-то написано.
**Подскажите примеры с вложенными пакетами**, находящимися в  самом приложении (тоесть не инсталлированных в общую папку)
Я подключаю так `params "./Packages/Params/"`
Структура приблизительно такая:

```
main.go (несколько файлов пакета main в одной папке)
-Packages
--PackagesGroup1
---package1.go
---SubPackagesGroup1
----subpackage1.go
--PackagesGroup2
---package2.go
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно писать полные пути пакетов относительно `$GOPATH/src`.
[Импорт пакета находящегося на уровень выше в GO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560000)

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/112168)

Comment: Я не вижу смысла дублировать ответ. Вопрос надо закрыть как дубль и дать ссылку на первый вариант или дать краткий ответ и ссылку на более полное описание (что я и сделал).