# Не могу импортировать пакет с другой директории

Tags: golang

Есть структура:

```
/golang
--/project
----main.go
----/init
------start.go
----/init2
------start2.go
```

Есть ошибка:

```
cannot find package c:\golang\project\init\project\init2
```

Главный файл `main.go`:

```
package main 

import (
    "./project/init"
)

func main() {

    stat.Valid()

}
```

И посредник `start.go`:

```
package stat

import (
    "./project/init2" // И вот тут я хочу импортировать init2 но мне не дает импортировать, ибо выскакивает ошибка cannot find package c:\golang\project\init\project\init2
)

func Valid() {

    stat_two.Valid2() // должен импортироваться пакет stat_two и функция Valid2

}
```

И `start2.go`:

```
package stat_two

import (
    "fmt"
)

func Valid2() {

    fmt.Println("succ import!")

}
```

Как я понял к адресу директории прибавляется ещё один адрес и получается `c:\golang\project\init\project\init2`. **Как мне импортировать другую директорию которая не лежит в текущей директории?** Чтоб получилось `c:\golang\project\init2`?

Comment: @Abyx Изменил, не правильно скорректировал свой вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Импорт пакета находящегося на уровень выше в GO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560000/%D0%98%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%B5-%D0%B2-go/560216#560216)

Ну и обратить внимание, что код проекта должен лежать в GOPATH\src (а не где угодно и не просто в GOPATH)

Comment: Спасибо большое!